# caption takes value from image alt attribute

Tags: jquery

I have this page in which the Jquery code is taking the alt value out and put it into a caption div under the thumbnail. but this code works only for the first one. now I want those caption to show under each pictures. ps. the number of the pictures vary, it could be 10 or may be 20.

the page url is here:

http://sydneyplants02.sajuk.com/Untitled-1.html

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy ..!!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.photogalleryItem').append(function () {
        return '<div class="caption">' + $(this).find('img').attr('alt') + '</div>';
    });
});
```

---

Reference

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td.photogalleryItem").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".caption").text($(this).find("img").attr("alt"));
    });
});
```

Comment: @wanghaipeng make sure you include jquery file. and write it under `document.ready`. See my edited answer.

Comment: i've updated the page, the part "td.photogalleryItem" is important, but every image has its own id. the current alt 1111111 is showing under every image, but it soposed to be like the caption text should be the alt value and put it under the image.

Comment: @wanghaipeng I have updated my answer. Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
$(function(){
    $('td.photogalleryItem').each(function(e) {
        var $caption = $('<div class="caption">');
        $caption.text($('img', $(this)).attr('alt'))
        $(this).append($caption);
    }
});
```

This will loop through each `td.photogalleryItem` and add a caption with the correct `alt` text. Your initial code was a start, but the issue was that it was only getting the `alt` text of the first `td.photogalleryItem`.